# Constantly Checking The Output From A Bash Command

Tags: bash

I have a script which calls an infinite command which outputs data and will never stop. I want to check if that command outputs a specific string, say "Success!", and then I'd like to stop it and move to the next line on my script.

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 2048x1536
until steam steam://run/730 | grep "Game removed" ; do
        :
done
echo "Success!"
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160
```

All my script does is to change resolution, start a Steam game, and then wait for a message to appear in the output which indicates the game was closed and change the resolution back to what it was.

The message I've mentioned appears every time, but the Steam process is still running. Could that be the problem?

If I close Steam manually then the script continues like I want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`until` built-in](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/until_loop) construct for this,

```
until command-name | grep -q "Success!"; do
   :
done
```

This will *wait* indefinitely until the string you want appears in `stdout` of your command, at which point `grep` succeeds and exits the loop. The `-q` flag in `grep` instructs it to run it silent and `:` is a short-hand for no-operation.

---

Difference between `until` and `while` - the former runs the loop contents until the exit-code of the command/operator used becomes `0` i.e. success, at which point it exits and `while` does the vice-versa of that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What if I'd like to `echo` something after I reached that string? Should I put it instead of the `:` or after `done`?

Comment: @AnDrOiD: It should be after `done`, remember the `:` part is for the infinite loop during which nothing is done. You may save a few CPU cycles by doing a sleep too!

Comment: Putting it after `done` was the first thing I tried, but it won't work for some reason. I took down the `-q` so I can be sure that it really reaches the string, and it does. What might be the problem?

Comment: @AnDrOiD: When the string appears in the command-output, the `until` loop actually breaks out and the _next_ instruction proceeding the loop should be executed. If you have an `echo` or `printf` following it, it should obviously work

Comment: @AnDrOiD: You said the problem yourself, your `steam` process is _running_. you need to kill/stop it _after_ the string is found to make sense